# Zodiac of Adar I

Tags: calendar, adar, astrology

The zodiac sign of the month Adar in a non-leap year is Pisces (Dagim). But what kind of Adar I, which is in a leap year? Two months cannot have the same zodiac sign.

Comment: "Two months cannot have the same zodiac sign." How do you know that? And does that apply if both months are Adar?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/26450) on Hidabroot, it's the first Adar that has the mazal of Dagim. The question should be what mazal the second Adar has. The answerer suggests that the reason that Dagim is plural rather than singular (dag) is because it can cover both months. However, there are views that the second Adar doesn't have a mazal at all (more sources can be seen [here](http://www.torahbase.org/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99/), section gimel).